# How to show latest date in sql with a condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

First Here's my table:

***Table: Swab***

```
| AutoID | Firstname | DateOfSpecimenCollection | isActive |  
    1       Aldrin           01/10/1990             TRUE                                                                                                                                    
    2       Aldrin           05/07/1996             TRUE
    3       Aldrin           09/02/2005             TRUE
    4       Aldrin           10/02/2012             FALSE
    5       Chris             (BLANK)               TRUE
    6       Chris            11/11/1999             FALSE
    7       James            12/12/2002             TRUE
    8       James            01/12/2006             TRUE
    9       James            05/05/2014             TRUE
```

***OUTPUT QUERY that i want***

```
| AutoID | Firstname | DateOfSpecimenCollection |
    3       Aldrin          09/02/2005 
    5       Chris             (BLANK)
    9       James           05/05/2014
```

Here, i want to create a query that will select a record of a person/user that has the latest `DateOfSpecimenCollection`. If the latest date with `isActive` set to `TRUE`, then it will output its own record. However , If the latest date with `isActive` set to `FALSE`, then it will output the record with the another latest date with `isActive` set to true(As shown from the example table above). If the record has no Date but has `isActive` condition set to `TRUE` it will still output its own record on the table(Note that if there's another record of Chris with a Date and `TRUE` Condition, that record will be outputed instead).

This is what i have done so far:

```
SELECT AutoID, Firstname, DateOfSpecimenCollection
FROM Swab
WHERE AutoID IN 

(SELECT TOP 1 AutoID FROM Swab AS Swab2 WHERE Swab2.PatientNo=Swab.PatientNo AND Swab.isActive = TRUE

ORDER BY Dupe.DateOfSpecimenCollection DESC);
```

It shows the correct information as above, However for some reason it doesn't select another record of a same person/user with the latest date and `TRUE` Condition. Instead it only sees the person with the latest date or the `TOP 1` and only return the record if the `isActive` is set to true which is not what i want.

The Query that i sent above look like this when it runs:

```
| AutoID | Firstname | DateOfSpecimenCollection |
    9        James           05/05/2014
```

I've also tried using the `IF()` Statement next to the `SELECT`, but i failed, it duplicates the record and also get the record with the previous dates. sorry for long  and confusing explanation and also for duplicate question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a correlated subquery to identify the matching records for each person is one option here:

```
SELECT AutoID, Firstname, DateOfSpecimenCollection
FROM Swab s1
WHERE DateOfSpecimenCollection = (SELECT MAX(s2.DateOfSpecimenCollection)
                                  FROM Swab s2
                                  WHERE s2.Firstname = s1.Firstname AND
                                        s2.isActive = 'TRUE');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation with group by

```
SELECT max(autoid) as autoid,Firstname,max(DateOfSpecimenCollection)
FROM Swab
where isActive = TRUE
group by Firstname
```

Comment: This query does not return the `AutoID`, which the OP seems to also want here.

Comment: really!! how Chiris autoid can be equal 2?? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: sorry, i was still writing the question, I didn't Know i posted it already, my bad

Comment: i edited the `AutoID` in the table above. I apologize for that.